# iPhone SDK: Access Localhost through iPad device possible? (while debugging)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

While running/debugging my app with an iPad real device, I want to a establish an internet connection to the localhost:8080 on my computer but it does not work! Why does it work with the simulator but not with a real device?

I want to test my app in a real device but not on a simulator..but thats not possible if I don't have an internet connection..is there a workaround for this in Xcode settings or in the actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator is actually running on localhost, the device isn't. Set the ip to the actual internal network ip of your machine running the web server.

Comment: Note you will need the phone to be on your wireless network for this to work.